# QGis QDir remove directory problem

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I am currently developing a QGis plugin and I need to create and remove directories and I use PyQt.
I don't know if my problem comes from PyQt or QGis. So my program creates folders, that works all good smoothly and stuff wow cool XD, then I can remove the empty folders with rmdir from QDir, that works too. the problem comes when there is files in the folder... In order to remove the non empty folders I first remove the files within using the QDir's remove method, that works fine all the files burns in hell and when I want to remove the folder, the rmdir method return True, like if everything was perfect but in fact no XD the folder's still here and became like "blocked" and I can't remove it from the program nor from windows "manually" ! And then only when I exit QGis, all the deletions are applied... I don't know where it comes from... I guess it's because of something like the directory is used by QGis but I don't know... so if you want to see the code ask for it because it's big and I didn't want to throw evrything ^^

Comment: Using the shutil module, does shutil.rmtree(myDir) delete the folder/files?

Comment: Yeah forgot to say that I also tried the exact same problem apears...

Comment: Have you tried `del myDir` before applying `shutil.rmtree(myDir)`?

Comment: but if i do that myDir will be None when i'll do the sutil.rmtree(myDir) no? then i don't see the point...

Comment: @Yorokobii - Apologies, you're right, I meant `shutil.rmtree('path/to/myDir')` where you define the path explicitly but I don't think this would be useful in a plugin.

Comment: Well I do something near using QDir.currentPath() to use an absolute path that is not really absolute tho but who cares XD

Comment: haaaalp ! XD I'm still struggling ! ^^ I don't know if commenting ups the topic... xD

Comment: So to complete a little bit I tried using only absolute paths and it doesn't work...

Comment: I also tried to "delete" using del all the QDir that I use... I'm more used to C++ so I wondered if it would change something or not but I don't think it's usefull in python... so yeah... I have no idea what's happening XD

Comment: So ! I tried to do a shutil.rmtree directly from the python console and the same problem occurs, then I did it from an external console and it worked so I guess Qgis blocks something...

Answer (score 1):

Okaaayy I found ! the problem comes from the Qgis browser... the thing where you can explore your folders and stuff... If the folder you want to delete is opened in there it wont delete it... so I just need to find a way to ensure that the folder is not opened in the browser !